# How to slide div item have 2 row in div parent HTML/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem div as in photo:

[image]

Items on div set `float:"left"` and this display Company 3, I not want that. I want row 1 have 3 div is "Company1, Company2, Company3" and row 2 have "Company4, Company5". When load page this show 1, 2, 4, 5 and hide 3 and click "next" this slide to left show Company3.

I need help. Thanks all.

```css
.slider{
  width: 355px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:50px auto;
 }
 .wrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 605px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #56c0ff;
 }
 .item-list-rank{
  float: left;
  width: 155px;
  max-height: 163px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-right: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 10px;
  .image{
   text-align: center;
  }
  .company-name{
   width: 100%;
   height: 35px;
   font:500 12px tahoma;
   text-align: center;
   a{text-decoration: none;color: #000;}
  }
  .job-name{
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   font:400 12px tahoma;
   text-align: center;
   a{text-decoration: none;color:#003fce;}
  }
  .time{
   width: 100%;
   // height: 20px;
   font:400 12px tahoma;
   text-align: center;
   color:#000;
   .no-time{color: #ff1919;}
  }
 }
 .prev{float: left;width: 200px;height: 50px;}
 .next{float: left;width: 100px;height: 50px;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item-list-rank">
                <div class="image"><img src="legalbiz-logo-company.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="company-name"><a href="">Company 1</a></div>
                <div class="job-name"><a href="">salesman</a></div>
                <div class="time"><span>deadline: </span><span class="no-time">expired</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-list-rank">
                <div class="image"><img src="legalbiz-logo-company.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="company-name"><a href="">Company 2</a></div>
                <div class="job-name"><a href="">salesman</a></div>
                <div class="time"><span>deadline: </span><span class="no-time">8/8/2016</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-list-rank">
                <div class="image"><img src="legalbiz-logo-company.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="company-name"><a href="">Company 3</a></div>
                <div class="job-name"><a href="">salesman</a></div>
                <div class="time"><span>deadline: </span><span class="no-time">expired</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-list-rank">
                <div class="image"><img src="legalbiz-logo-company.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="company-name"><a href="">Company 4</a></div>
                <div class="job-name"><a href="">salesman</a></div>
                <div class="time"><span>deadline: </span><span class="no-time">expired</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-list-rank">
                <div class="image"><img src="legalbiz-logo-company.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="company-name"><a href="">Company 5</a></div>
                <div class="job-name"><a href="">salesman</a></div>
                <div class="time"><span>deadline: </span><span class="no-time">8/8/2016</span></div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <span class="prev">prev</span>
  <span class="next">Next</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: From what I can comprehend from your question, using CSS flexbox would make this much easier to do.

Comment: When i Flex this only show 1 row and hiden Company 4 5. I don't want that.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm struggling to understand your question; I assume that English is not your first language, and that you may be struggling with it (though I do respect the effort you've made!), would you be able to ask a friend, or colleague, to review your question with the aim of improving it for those of us that speak English? This should - hopefully - lead to you getting better answers more relevant to your problem, and fewer 'best-guesses' at solutions.